# how to fix Root type mapping not empty after parsing! error in Elasticsearch to create dynamic mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have created the the Dynamic mapping for index in run time using java API .the mapping Value is formed correctly but it throws

> Error: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:

I have searched all the possibilities but wont get solution.the formed mapping value is `{"Index":{"properties":{"dynamic_template":[{"template_1":{"path_match":"*"},"f1":{"type":"String","include_in_all":true},"f2":{"type":"String","include_in_all":true},"f3":{"type":"String","include_in_all":true},"f4":{"type":"String","include_in_all":true}}]}}}`

The Error message is

> Error: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:   [casesheet : {properties={dynamic_template=[{template_1={path_match=*}, f1={type=String, include_in_all=true}, f2={type=String, include_in_all=true}, f3={type=String, include_in_all=true}, f4={type=String, include_in_all=true}}]}}]

I have no idea to fix it.Is any one guide me to fix it.

Comment: I think it should be `"match":"*"` and not `"path_match":"*"`.

Comment: Hi Andrei Stefan thanks for your response i had tried the "match":"*".In this case also occurs the same error.